# Таблица Менделеева в html

Tags: html

Как сделать таблицу Менделеева в html?
Напишите хотя бы код одной ячейки)

Comment: 15 минут и будет готово)

Comment: а как сделать так чтобы она была номером и массой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это одна ячейка. Все остальные - аналогично.
Общий вид таблицы вам уже показал @Gorets. =)

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid">
  <tr>
    <th>24</th>
    <td rowspan="3" style="font-size: 66px">Cr</td>
    <td>Хром</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><small><u>52</u>-54</small></td>
    <td>s<sup>1</sup>d<sup>5</sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>51,996</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <table style="border: 1px solid">
<tr><th>24</th><td rowspan="3" style="font-size: 66px">Cr</td><td>Хром</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="2"><small><u>52</u>-54</small></td><td>s<sup>1</sup>d<sup>5</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td>51,996</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: вставил код - выше результат, но что-то химическое я там вижу =)

Comment: Здесь бесполезно вставлять результат. Например фонт-сайз выпиливается

Comment: Галочка слева

Comment: Картинками легче всего! КАРТИНКАМИ

Comment: одной картинкой, стыренной из гугла. ;)

Comment: И так тоже!  
Или программисты не ищут легких путей???

Comment: Иногда требуется сделать интеррактивным каждый элемент. Например, изменить округление массы, скрыть те или иные числа, подсветить ту или иную структуру, добавить поля и т.п. в режиме работы с таблицей. Плакат на стене не столь удобен.

Comment: В фотошопе не надо никакого HTML. Подправили картинку быстренько, и мигом обновить! ГЫ :)

Answer (score 3):

Я не химик, но суть я думаю ясна! Подставить, убрать лишнее, нужное закрасить)

```html
<table cellpadding="10" border="1">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>II</td>
    <td>III</td>
    <td>IV</td>
    <td>V</td>
    <td>VI</td>
    <td>VII</td>
    <td colspan="4">VIII</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>II</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#95cfff">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cb9cfc">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cb9cfc">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cb9cfc">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cb9cfc">Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#cb9cfc">Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>III</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
    <td bgcolor="#fffca3">Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
    <td rowspan="2">IV</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2">5</td>
    <td rowspan="2">V</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2">6</td>
    <td rowspan="2">VI</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2">7</td>
    <td rowspan="2">VII</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Symb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ну че ты так =) целых полчаса, почти, =) а говорил всего 15 минут ))))

Comment: На работе попутно еще шпарю)))

Answer (score 1):

```html
<TABLE BORDER=1 bordercolor=darkblue>
  <CAPTION ALIGN=bottom> Таблица Менделеева </CAPTION>
  <TR>
    <TH>елементы</TH>
    <TH>елементы</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE BORDER=1 bordercolor=darkblue>
  <CAPTION ALIGN=bottom> Таблица Менделеева </CAPTION>
  <TR>
    <TH>елементы</TH>
    <TH>елементы</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>елементы</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```